# Top Level Element is not Compaleted

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I'm really new to this and I've searched for answers but none seem relevant. When I build my android project I have an error. See at the bottom of this xml. Where do I go to find this "top level element" and why might it be incomplete?:

here code in my rowdata.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listJudul"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Judul Buku"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listNama"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nama"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listTglPinjam"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tgl Pinjam"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listStatus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Status"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="13sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You forgot to include the error message, but I think you've accidentally closed the second `LinearLayout` early (with `/>` instead of just `>`)

Comment: yeah i'm forgot to include the error message sorry,  you're right  I'm closed the second `Linear Layout` with `/>`  , Thank you for the help @IMSoP